# I want an image carousel similar to Amazon's product carousel

Tags: jquery

I want an image carousel similar to Amazon's product carousel in asp.net. when i will click on next or prev button the list of images will load from server after ajax call. if anyone knows about somethings similar then please let me know.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [ContentFlow](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/), specifically the [roundabout addon](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/addons.php). It don't think it uses jQuery, but it is written in Javascript.